# Returning Rendered Html via Ajax

Tags: django

I am trying to return html via and Ajax call and I have the following snippet of code in my view

```
if request.is_ajax(): 
t = loader.get_template('frontend/scroll.html')
html = t.render(RequestContext({'dishes': dishes})
return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'html': html}))
```

and my Ajax

```
  $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "/filter_home", 
           data: {'name': 'me', 'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{csrf_token}}'},
           success : function(data) {
                $('.row.replace').html(data);
            }
   });
```

and it throws the following error

```
Exception Value:    'dict' object has no attribute 'META'
Exception Location: /opt/bitnami/apps/django/lib/python2.7/sitepackages/django/core/context_processors.py in debug, line 39
```

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

There are a few issues with your code:

You need to use [`render_to_string`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/templates/#django.template.loader.render_to_string).

You also don't need to convert your HTML into json because you are replacing the contents directly.

Putting all this together you have:

```
from django.template.loader import render_to_string
from django.http import HttpResponse

if request.is_ajax():
    html = render_to_string('frontend/scroll.html', {'dishes': dishes})
    return HttpResponse(html)
```

In your front end, you need:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/filter_home", 
        data: {'name': 'me', 'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{ csrf_token }}'},
        success : function(data) {
             $('.row.replace').html(data);
         }
});
```

Comment: I have been getting an error, nothing has showed up on the page via ajax, I printed the error with a jquery alert and I see the following message "SyntaxError: Unexpected token <". Is ajax not recognizing the html opening tag?

Comment: If the AJAX call returns HTML, the trick is to use `$('#result').html(data)` instead of `$('#result').text(data)` (notice **`.html`** instead of `.text`).

Comment: @jabba The issue with using .html() tag to replace the div is that you need to select the parent div first to replace the same contents inside. A better technique is to use .replaceWith

Answer (score 0):

The first argument of RequestContext is a request object.

You could either add the request object or use the Context class instead.

Answer (score -1):

First parameter to `RequestContext()` should be `request`, so update line in your code as

```
html = t.render(RequestContext(request, {'dishes': dishes})
```